# IOKIT mac os IORegistryEntry

Tags: xcode, frameworks, iokit

I want to know how to link the `IOKit.framework` using the below code. I cannot link it in my application: XCode always warns me that the methods I am using are unknown. I know there are **usage restrictions**, <del>for example in kernel extensions only</del>: the I/O Kit uses an object-oriented programming model, implemented in a **restricted subset of C++** to promote increased code reuse, as specified in [I/O Kit Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/IOKit/IOKit.html) . If you can help me it will be with great pleasure so that I can learn.

```
 OSData * data;
 IORegistryEntry * entry;
 OSString * string = 0;
 uuid_string_t uuid;
 const IORegistryPlane * gIODTPlane;



 entry = IORegistryEntry :: fromPath ("/efi/platform", gIODTPlane);
 if (entry)
 {
     data = OSDynamicCast (OSData, entry-> getProperty ("SystemSerialNumber"));
     if (data && data-> getLength () == 16)
     {
         string = OSString :: withCString ((char const *) data-> getBytesNoCopy ());
     }

     entry-> release ();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Those types and functions are all defined in the `Kernel.framework`. Unless you're building a kernel extension, that's not what you want. The user space API for accessing the IOKit is via a C API (IOKitLib) provided by the `IOKit.framework`.

Documentation for this is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_IOKitLib_API/AH_IOKitLib_API.html

Looks like you want the `IORegistryEntryFromPath()` and `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty()` functions to get the information you want in user space.

(Both are declared in `<IOKit/IOKitLib.h>`, make sure you add the IOKit.framework to your target's list of libraries to link against. You may also need to link against CoreFoundation.framework if your app doesn't already link to it or the Cocoa.framework.)

Comment: Good evening thank you, for the link to the very austere apple documentation API, I almost reached my goals, diverting the ioreg., A lot of code for a result, so when using the kernel.framework in 2 lines it is set. thank you for the time spent answering.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer which is the correct answer, the difference between the two versions, the first gives a usable result immediately after conversion "withCString" and "OSData" (C ++), the 2nd version (withIORegistryEntryFromPath () and IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty ()) a conversion is mandatory and it can also be used in "C", it is longer. For Key that are not official, it's hard to target, like ioreg.c, using a "CFMutableDictionaryRef" to get a result. Thanks again for the time

Comment: Can you tell me how to get (segment offset) each different plane (IODeviceTree, IOService ....) to make a dump? thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

below the use of "CFMutableDictionaryRef" with "IORegistryEntryFromPath", "IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties" and "CFDictionaryApplyFunction", you get the block contained in "platform" which it has sorted each element with conversion string or data.This is what exists with ioreg.c in a very light form

```
void getsystemuuid()
{

    io_registry_entry_t service  = 0;
    struct options      options;
    CFMutableDictionaryRef properties = 0;
    kern_return_t       status      = KERN_SUCCESS;


    service = IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IODeviceTree:/efi/platform");

    status=IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties( service,&properties,kCFAllocatorDefault,kNilOptions );

    if (status)
        goto sortie;


    CFDictionaryApplyFunction(properties, showitem,&options.depth);

sortie:
    CFRelease(properties);
    IOObjectRelease(service);
}
```